# Different to get the output between?

Tags: python, linux

Could be any different to get the output between the next commands:

```
lsof_list = commands.getoutput('lsof  | awk \'{print $1,$2,$5}\')
```

or:

```
lsof_list1 = commands.getoutput('lsof  | awk \'{print $1}\')
lsof_list2 = commands.getoutput('lsof  | awk \'{print $2}\')
lsof_list5 = commands.getoutput('lsof  | awk \'{print $5}\') 
lsof_list = [lsof_list1, lsof_list2, lsof_list5]
```

of course, rows are going to be columns and vice-versa,  but I main doubt is about the data, can be possible that there will be different number of open files during the time the code is working?

To be sure, is there any function to execute few commands in Python at the same time?

Comment: Code highlighting is your friend. You're missing trailing single quotes (`'`) in all of your examples.

Comment: The sheer fact of launching a new process may alter the output of `lsof`... so the first example is the correct one... and your second makes little sense... What are you actually trying to do - what is the reasoning for this question - the example doesn't help :)

Comment: Im making a function to save the data from lsof in a database, the problem with the first one is when there is some empty space.

Comment: @JohnSnow what does "empty space" mean? How would running the same command three times and putting it back together solve that issue? It sounds like you want to do some extra work on processing the data first...

Comment: @JonClements I mean that some time when lsof is called it return some "empty cells", then I cant find the way to split properly without jump over the result of empty cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah there can be difference in the output. In first case you are executing `lsof` only once and then capturing the values from `lsof` output but in second case `lsof` is exeucted 3 times  which might result in different output.